# How to add functionality to SearchResultsButton in search bar with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to have a sheet pop up when the SearchResultsButton on my search bar is tapped. The below picture shows the button I want to add functionality for:

[image]

This is the code I have currently:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isSearching = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hello")
                Text("World")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
            .searchable(text: $isSearching)
            .onAppear {
                UISearchBar.appearance().showsSearchResultsButton = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about accomplishing my goal? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to create your own

Comment: @loremipsum How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Textfield, button, circle, arrow, etc

Comment: @loremipsum There isn't a way I can use UIKit interoperability to accomplish this?

Comment: I doubt it, I've never tried but highly doubt it.